# How do you change the From: field in an email's header using Outlook or Exchange online?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I have been tasked with automating a process: getting GMS email alerts to automatically create tickets in ConnectWise, ***AND*** automatically assign the proper client.

In our environment we have a SonicWALL GMS that sends out email alerts. The GMS monitors 20 different SonicWALLS for 20 different clients.

The alerts are sent **from** sender@domian.com. 
The emails are sent **to** a distribution group gmsalert@domain.com. 
In this distribution group is the member ticketingsystem@domain.com. When an email is received by ticketingsystem@domain.com, a ticket is automatically created in our ticketing system. This mail flow is working properly, no problems there.

Here's the challenge: in order to get the ticketing system to automatically select the company field for the company, the FROM: field needs to be a company contact. For example: gms@clientX.com

What I need is a rule that can change the from email address: sender@domain.com to a client contact email address gms@clientX.com, based on the SonicWALL serial number in the subject or body of the email. I don't need to redirect the email, I can get it TO the right place, I just need to change where the email is FROM, so the ticketing system assigns the correct client

I have researched this extensively. I've tried Outlook rules, but can't find one that will "send as" a different user. I have researched Exchange mail flow rules that adjust message header information, even opened a ticket with Office 365 support, and they hit a dead end as well. Does anyone have any insight on how to change the From: field in an email's header using Outlook or Exchange online?

*************EDIT***************
For clarity I have added a diagram that shows the flow and what needs to happen. The To: field does not need to change. The emails are being delivered to where they need to go. When they get to where they are going, the From: field needs to change.

[image: mail flow diagram]

Comment: Talking about Outlook rules... Do you need to automatically redirect incoming messages to another email address from client contact's email (that is an Exchange contact and you have the "Send As" permissons for it)?

Comment: No, I don't need to redirect. I can get the email TO the right place, I just need to change where the email is FROM, so the ticketing system assigns the correct client.

Comment: So it comes in to the distribution group directly from the program? And you need to, do what? Have it come into a different mailbox in the distribution group which then forwards it to the ticketing system, but changes its identity based on the program's email?

Comment: The GMS (single point of SMTP) sends an alert in an email, always FROM sender@domain.com. It goes to the distribution group gmsalert@domain.com and then to the ticketing system. By the time the email gets to the ticketing system, the From: address, sender@domain.com needs to be changed to one of about 30 different client contact addresses: gms@clientX.com, which is based on the serial number of the device contained in the body of the email. I do not need to alter the destination. I need to alter the sent from field of the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that is available in unmodified Exchange, much less Outlook.  I have accomplished the exact same thing in two ways.

1) We use IronPort ESA filters/SMTP nodes to accept mail.  You can write a rule at this level to do what you are asking before delivering to Exchange.  The idea is simple enough and many mail filters will have similar capabilities.  Have a mail content rule that triggers if the sender is 'GMS' and body contains serial number 'xyz' (lots of rules, one for each SN); the action is to modify the envelope-sender address to your desired address.
Do be wary that you are talking about modifying to an address with a domain that is sounds like you don't control.  Depending on where in the process your filter performs sender verification & anti-spoof/spam your alteration of the from address may cause failures to deliver.  Just be mindful that there may be additional changes this requires.

2) I have written a custom SMTP Mail Transfer Agent in .Net, my code was to strip & re-route attachments (we didn't want large attachments living in our Exchange server, so the ESA would send emails over a certain size to my MTA that would move the attachments to a file server and insert links to the offloaded files into the message body).  You can do the same thing, get a custom MTA that reads the body and changes the from address based upon some lookup information.  "If SN matches devices.SN then set From as devices.ContactEmail" type process.  You'll need someone to do the coding for you (assuming that isn't in your skillset, if it is, boom, you're all set).  Then your MTA just hands the re-written output to the Exchange inbound connector.

No, you can't do this in native Exchange (and especially in Exchange Online, where changing FROM address to non-authoritative domains is a pretty frowned upon thing).  But it can be done.

Comment: For clarity, I used the IIS6 SMTP agent to accept the emails and drop them as .msg files in the DROP folder; then my service (with a folder watcher) would pick those up for processing and send the processed email to Exchange.  I didn't write a full MTA, but the same end result was achieved.  And always be careful when re-writing the FROM address as you can easily trigger spam/spoof detection rules.

Comment: Your first point is our back up plan. I'm also asking the ticketing system if they can scrape the return-path field. I can alter the return-path field in the header.

Comment: Depending on the number of clients you have to write rules for, if the mail already traverses some form of smart filter then #1-like is the way I'd go.  It could just be a pain to keep up-to-date with individual rules.  A custom transport rule in Exchange could do it as well, but you'd have to write that and extending the transport pipe is something I normally argue against

Comment: Currently the client list is only about 20 in the GMS, so it's manageable.

Comment: Another (and wholly untested) thought.  If you can alter the return field in GMS, you might be able to have a rule in your mail filter that IF From==GMS THEN Set From=Return-Path.  That'd be one rule in the email filter and would be easily expandable/updatable using only GMS in the future...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for those using Exchange Online (365):

My Situation:
I had essentially the same problem (as Ben) where I had a vendor sending status emails to our ticketing system that I wanted to automatically assign to one of our clients.
The only option that I could change on our vendor's end was the email where notices were sent.

Our email is hosted through Exchange Online (365), so that limited our options.
We did not have any SMTP filters that could be configured to help us.

My Solution (aka What worked for me):
1. What I did was to set up one shared mailbox for each client (for me this was 7 shared mailboxes total). 
2. Then I logged into the web mailbox for a given client and went to
"Settings -> Mail -> Automatic Processing -> Inbox and sweep rules"
where I created a rule to forward any mail from our vendor to our ticket system.
3. Then I added that shared mailbox address to our ticket system's contact list as a contact under the correct client.
4. The final step was to change the notification email from our vendor to send mail to the shared mailbox associated with each of our clients.

Limitations (That I know of):
- This does leave the message have the "FW: " appended to the email subject line as well as the typical message forward text saying the original sender, recipient, and time at the top of the email body text.
This really did not make a difference for our techs, but may be a deal breaker for someone.

Other Thoughts:
- I imagine the same thing could be done using the desktop version of Outlook, but then Outlook would have to remain open to forward the messages.
- This solution works well for us since Shared Mailboxes don't require an active 365 license, so there is no extra cost.
- I also set up a rule that would automatically delete the automatic replies from our ticketing system and other junk mail just to keep the mailbox clean.
- Finally, I have also used this setup to include a couple programs we use that require a SMTP server. What I did was to give a normal mail account Full Access and Send As permissions to the shared mailboxes. (We had a maintenance account so that is what I used.) Then I could enter the 365 SMTP settings with the login being our maintenance account and the "send as" was the client specific mailbox. The program was then set to email directly to our ticket system and shows up as coming from the shared mailbox. (NOTE: The normal mail account will require an active license since it has to log into the mail server. I used our maintenance email because all of our normal user emails require password changes ever 90 days, which would require us to constantly update the password on our programs as well, but our maintenance email is a static password.)

Hopefully this helps someone else with their problem.